# JMS Serializer: How to limit the depth of serialisation for an object graph

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

Maybe it is just my misunderstanding of this annotation however it does not seam to work as expected.

I have the following object graph

```
User
 -> Company
  -> Users
   -> Groups
    -> Permissions
```

As you can see there will be some recursion. JMS handles this quite well by not serialising the other user's company properties as well as not the current user.

However I want the serialization to stop at and include company.

I have tried this expecting that once the level $context->level = 2 it would stop

```
<?php
namespace FinalConcept\TimeTracker\EntitiesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * FinalConcept\TimeTracker\EntitiesBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FinalConcept\TimeTracker\EntitiesBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="company", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @JMS\MaxDepth(depth=1)
     */
    private $company;
}
```

However this is not the case. Even stepping through the code has not shed any light on how to stop this.

I am happy to create a custom handler if I can only invoke it for a specific path i.e. User.Company

I also need this for User.Groups which has the following graph

```
User
 -> Groups
  -> Permissions
 -> Users
   -> Groups
     -> users ....
```

Thanks in advance for any help how to limit the depth of serialization for an object graph

Comment: Hey thank you for your amazing response. is it possible to mention `@MaxDepth` on the hole class??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because I did not have access to the latest version of the serializer I had to find a workaround to the @MaxDepth. This may also help you.

Use  @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all") on all entities that are connected.

Now use @JMS\Expose only on those properties that you want to have serialize.
On join relations only use this annotation in one direction. That will fix your problem.

```
namespace FinalConcept\TimeTracker\EntitiesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * FinalConcept\TimeTracker\EntitiesBundle\Entity
 *
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FinalConcept\TimeTracker\EntitiesBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
     /**
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="company", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $company;
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your amazing response. is it possible to mention `@MaxDepth` on the hole class??

Comment: No sry. @MaxDepth is marked as property/Method annontation @Target({"PROPERTY","METHOD"})

Answer (score 4):

As of the latest version, using @MaxDepth() annotation and SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks() in the controller does the job.