# FOSRest view entity with ManyToMany association prevent deep nested json array

Tags: arrays, json, symfony, fosrestbundle

My title is probably not the best; i find difficulty in finding a short description of the problem.

I have 2 objects:
Object and Element (with a ManyToMany association)

Object:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ObjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="object")
 */
class Object {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Element", inversedBy="objects", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name ="objects_elements")
     */
     protected $elements;


     function __toString() {
        return $this->getName();
     }

getters and setters....
```

And Element:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ElementRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="element")
 */
class Element {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Object", mappedBy="elements", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $objects;

getters and setters....
```

The controller extends the FOSRestController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Api;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Object;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;


/**
 * Object controller.
 *
 * @Route("/object")
 */
class ObjectController extends FOSRestController {

    /**
     * Show Object entitie.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit/api", options={"expose"=true}, name="object_show_api")
     * @Method("GET")
     * 
     */
    public function jsonShowAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Object')->findOneById($id);

        $view = $this->view($entity
                        , 200)
                ->setTemplate("object/json.html.twig");


        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```

The output of the controller is the following json:

```
{
    "object": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Object 3",
        "elements": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Element 1",
            "objects": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Object 2a",
                "elements": [],
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to prevent that in "elements" the array "objects" is shown, because there "elements" will be shown again, and so on...

Whats the proper way to achieve this?
I prefer that the output will be something like this:

```
{
    "object": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Object 3",
        "elements": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Element 1",
        }]
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the relationship between objects and elements to be unidirectional:
Objects side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Element", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name ="objects_elements")
 */
 protected $elements;
```

Element side:

```
null
```

And check and correct eventual error (optional):

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:valid
```

or for Symfony < 3

```
app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

finally remove the old setter/getter and the objects property in Element class and do:

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle:Element
```

Remember you have to rwite a custome repository method like getObjects() from the ElementRepository if you want to get all the objects links to an Element. I hope it help.

Comment: Thanks. I finally ended up using jms serializer in combination with this solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590073/jms-serializer-how-to-limit-the-depth-of-serialisation-for-an-object-graph